# AngularJS radio button issue

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have the following in a jade file

```
....
input(id='prefChangeY', type='radio', ng-value='Yes', ng-model='form.prefChange', name='prefChange', on-focus="fieldInfo='Select yes to change your pref'")
.....
input(id='prefChangeN', type='radio', ng-value='No', ng-model='form.prefChange', name='prefChange', on-focus="fieldInfo='Select no to change your pref'")
.....
```

In the controller I have the following code

```
$scope.form.prefChange = 'No';
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to get the No radio button to be selected by default.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Melroy

Answer (score 2):

Use `value` instead of `ng-value`. Check the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.radio).

```
value='Yes'
value='No'
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LNWNz/

Answer (score 1):

The attribute for the value when selected is not `ng-value` but simply `value`.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.radio

```
<input type="radio"
   ng-model="{string}"
   value="{string}"
   [name="{string}"]
   [ng-change="{string}"]>
```

Comment: To be fair: sza actually answered this correctly first. I first gave a wrong answer because I misread the question and then deleted, edited and undeleted it. sza was a little faster with his answer then. So the answer by sza should be "Accepted" in my opinion.